# Adding custom dropdown(values dynamically from db) in the lead form in vTiger

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

I am new to **vtiger crm** and need a code to add the dropdown that has values from the database table in add lead page.
Please provide a solution if somebody have ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add drop-down field by using bellow code and follow the steps to achieve your result:

1. Add bellow code in one PHP file (e.g add_to_lead.php).
2. Put that file into your project directory.
3. Run that file from browser (e.g www.yourVtigerhost.com/add_to_lead.php)

   ```
   $Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
   include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
   include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');

   $module = new Vtiger_Module();
   $module = $module->getInstance('Leads');

   // Create new Block into Lead Module and your drop-down added into new block
   $block1 = new Vtiger_Block();
   $block1->label = 'LBL_LEAD_INFORMATION';
   $block1 = $block1->getInstance($block1->label,$module);

   $field0 = new Vtiger_Field();
   $field0->name = 'your field name';
   $field0->table = $module->basetable;
   $field0->label = 'Your field Name to display';
   $field0->column = 'field_name';
   $field0->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
   $field0->uitype = 15;
   $field0->setPicklistValues( Array ('Dropdown Value1','Dropdown Value2','Dropdown Value3'));
   $field0->typeofdata = 'V~O';
   $block1->addField($field0);
   ```

New Dropdown have values like *Dropdown Value1,Dropdown Value2,Dropdown Value3*

If you want to add more values into dropdown than you can add from **Setting-> Studio->Picklist Editor**.

Comment: thanks for response @gautam  but this will add a static dropdown and need a dynamic drop down ,values fetch values from db .

Comment: These values are also store into Vtiger database table. From which table's value you want display into dropdown?

Comment: basically what i want to do is to show the list of customer in dropdown on the lead page ,which will fetch from the custom database table or module table

Comment: please try with my updated script, i missed to getInstance of Lead module.

Comment: thanks for updated code , One thing more i want to know that ,Is there any option to add the array values in custom key=>value pair. e.g('hello'=>'world','hello1'=>'world1') and save in same manner ?

Comment: you cann't use the associative array, You can add dropdown into Lead module so one table is created for that dropdown like 'vtiger_your-fieldname'. you can right a script that import or insert data from your custom table/ database to your new  'vtiger_your-fieldname' table.